# map iterator in template function unrecognized by compiler

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, iterator

I have the following code.

```
template<class key,class val>
bool has_key(key chkey,std::map<key,val> map){
  for (std::map<key,val>::iterator it = map.begin(); #line 13 referenced by gcc
      it!=map.end(); ++it){
    if(chkey == it->first) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

GCC is giving me the following error.

```
objects.hpp: In function `bool has_key(key, std::map<key, val, std::less<_Key>,
  std::allocator<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> > >)':
objects.hpp:13: error: expected `;' before "it"
objects.hpp:14: error: `it' was not declared in this scope
```

Somehow "it" is not being initialized, what in Sam Hain is going on here?!

Comment: Duplicates include: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301380/g-is-not-a-type-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841757/c-template-is-not-derived-from-type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931345/c-trouble-with-dependent-types-in-templates

Comment: Sidenote: Are you sure you want to pass your map by value instead of const reference and use const_iterator?

Comment: pmr, thanks for the suggestion.  const use is a practice I havn't gotten into yet and need to develop habits around.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need the `typename` keyword:

```
for (typename std::map<key,val>::iterator it = map.begin(); #line 13 referenced by gcc
  it!=map.end(); ++it){
```

See also: [Why do we need typename here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123080/why-do-we-need-typename-here)

This is because you are in a template definition and `iterator` is a dependent name. This has been asked before.

[g++ "is not a type" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301380/g-is-not-a-type-error)

[C++ Template: 'is not derived from type'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841757/c-template-is-not-derived-from-type)

[Trouble with dependent types in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931345/c-trouble-with-dependent-types-in-templates)