# Template std::map::iterator instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)
>   [map iterator in template function unrecognized by compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184682/map-iterator-in-template-function-unrecognized-by-compiler)

I have a template function which has `std::map::iterator` instantiation within it -

```
template <class B , class C> 
C getValue (B& myMap , C returnType) {
    map<string,C>::iterator it = myMap.find(var);
    // implementation ...
}
```

and it prompt errors  -

```
In function ‘C getValue(char*, B&, C)’:
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
```

How should I have make it properly ?

Comment: You can use `auto it = myMap.find(var);`.

Comment: @Zoidberg'-- : what is this auto ? can your give more details please ?

Comment: @URL87: using `auto` like that is a recent addition to the language. It declares the variable to have the same type as its initialiser. It's very useful in cases like this where the type can be awkward (or even impossible) to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a dependent type so you need `typename`:

```
typename map<string,C>::iterator it = myMap.find(var);
```

See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for *much* more detail.

As commented by [Zoidberg'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142019/zoidberg), C++11 has `auto` which instructs the compiler to deduce the type. See [Elements of Modern C++ Style](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/) for a brief overview (with some other features).