# C++: error "... is not derived from type ..."

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Bimap {
public:
    class Data;
    typedef Data* DataP;    
    typedef std::multimap<T1, DataP> T1Map;
    typedef std::multimap<T2, DataP> T2Map;

    class Data {
    private:
        Bimap& bimap;
        T1Map::iterator it1;
        /*...*/
    };
};
```

This gives me this compile error:

`error: type 'std::multimap<T1, Bimap<T1, T2>::Data*, std::less<_Key>, std::allocator<std::pair<const T1, Bimap<T1, T2>::Data*> > >' is not derived from type 'Bimap<T1, T2>::Data'`

What does that mean? What is the problem here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Template: 'is not derived from type'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841757/c-template-is-not-derived-from-type)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

make it:

```
typename T1Map::iterator it1;
```

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I always forget about that. And that error message really was not helpful to remind me about it.