# Thinking in C++ error in source code

Tags: c++, templates

I am reading the book Thinking in C++ (2nd edition Vol 1) and i have a problem when i try to compile this source code:

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_c++/Chapter16_015.html

The problem appears to be in that line:

Stack::Link* p;

As i have read in [C++: error "... is not derived from type ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746377/c-error-is-not-derived-from-type)
i have to add the word "typename" (or "class") in front of it.

Is the book wrong in this example or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's wrong. You need the `typename`. See the [typename and template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-to-put-the-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names/613132#613132) FAQ entry.

`Stack` is a dependent type and `Stack::List` is a dependent type too. This is *legal* in C++0x, but it's illegal in current C++.

Comment: and what about in C++98, the version that was current when the book was released?

Comment: @Ben It was needed there aswell. The only change I remember offhead introduced to C++03 that's remotely relevant here is that the *unqualified* name `List` was made a dependent type. But that of course is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the book wrong in this example or am I missing something?

I've found that different compilers have different requirements for the `typename` keyword. MSVC is fairly forgiving, gpp is more strict.

Answer (score 0):

It's more a case of you using too old a book.  The publication date of that book is 2000, meaning much of the actual writing was taking place when the C++98 standard was being finalized.

The current version of C++ is C++03, and C++0x is fast approaching standardization.

I don't think that `typename` was required in C++98.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late in day but the code should compile if you change

Stack::Link* p;

to just

Link* p;